# What is the best and fast ORM to use with Oracle for .NET?

Tags: .net, orm

What is the best and fast ORM to use with Oracle for .NET ?  Based on your evaluation , experience etc. (to replace my existing data layer for oracle)

**fast =** operations per second

**best =** lest time to learn and does not have any high fi mumbo jumbo

Need to load 10,000 or more records and update them in 10 mins or less... on oracle.

Comment: To me, it sounds as if you don't need an ORM at all. Just use SQL. When using an ORM, such huge batch operations are usually still done with SQL, because it is most efficient. NHibernate allows updates using HQL without loading them in memory. But I don't think that you gain anything.

Comment: We're going to run tests for Oracle (+ few other databases) at ORMBattle.NET shortly. I hope in January, but since this is a free time work for us, a lot depends on stress @ our primary job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define "best" and "fast". Are you looking at learning curve (i.e. fast to learn), performance, speed of development once you know what you are doing with it? Are you looking for distributed cache support or anything non-standard? There are always edge cases where you can make a non-ORM solution slightly faster than an ORM solution, so if you are really looking for "fastest", do you even want an ORM in the first place?

If you're relatively new to ORMs, then NHibernate has good community support, including Fluent NHibernate to help with the learning curve. But we'd need to know more about your real priorities to make a firm recommendation.

Comment: Not new to ORMs just that the one I am using now is slow with oracle and I need to process huge amount or data(take and update)

Comment: So what's slow about the one you currently use? At the end of the day, an ORM should just be chucking SQL at the DBMS. Is yours generating inefficient SQL, or does it come with some other code overhead?

Comment: Its so slow on oracle but fast on sql server :-(

Comment: As a matter of interest, what ORM are you currently using?